# Redis - delete field by pattern matching on hash key

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have the following structure in Redis,

```
commKey:hkey1
    target1 - value1
    target2 - value2
commKey:hkey2
    target2 - value3
    target3 - value4
commKey:hkey3
    target1 - value5
    target3 - value6
...
```

commkey will appear on all hashkeys followed by a namespace and a unique string(hkey1, hkey2, hkey3...). I want to remove all target1 s in all keys. `target1` appears in `commKey:hkey1` and `commKey:hkey3`. So, this is something like match `commKey:*` and del `target1`. I tried to do it with `hscan` which enables pattern match on subkeys(fields). But I need to do it on "haskkey". How to do it in an efficient way? Thanks in advance.

PS: We have `commKey` because in future we may want to add another type of hashkey which don't start with `commKey` and it should not be affected by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should scan the keys, not the hash.

1. Use `SCAN` command to get keys that match `commKey:*`
2. For each key, call `HDEL` to remove the given target, no matter whether the hash has such a field or not.

Comment: That's a possible way. we need to do two operations. `SCAN` and `HDEL`. Isn't it possible with single operation? Is there any way to do combine both match and delete

Comment: @RaR AFAIK, there's no such way... If you find one, please share it with me :)

Comment: Later I found that the actual need is to do scan as well as hscan. `SCAN` with match `commKey:*` and for each key returned, have to do `HSCAN` with match `target1*`. Then for each result have to perform `HDEL`. To avoid these many steps, I was looking for as easier and minimal way